# Log file monitoring with zabbix 3

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

My objective is to get notified every time when the word "alert" occurrence has been detected in a specific Log file :

*/var/log/apache2/test-error.log*

**steps I did** :

1 - ensure configuration between zabbix's server and agent

2 - zabbix user in the host has right to read the log file

3 - an item is created with the following key :

```
log[/var/log/apache2/test-error.log,alert]
```

4 - a trigger has been created with the following expression :

```
{ha3.datacenter.ma:log[/var/log/apache2/test-error.log,alert].str(server)}=1
```

**Problem** :

the trigger stat always is OK, where they are multiple lines added to the log file witch match the regex continuously !

Answer (score 3):

You said you want the trigger to fire whenever string `alert` is detected, but your trigger seems to check for the string `server` instead: `str(server)`.

After that is fixed, make sure that:

- item is actually getting the values (http://zabbix.org/wiki/Troubleshooting might be helpful here)
- trigger option "Multiple PROBLEM event generation" is set

Comment: sorry, but how to make sure that item is actually getting the values ?

Comment: That's a different topic, and it is not suggested to mix multiple questions - if you see that the item is indeed not getting any values and can't make it work, please post a new question. This troubleshooting page might be helpful: http://zabbix.org/wiki/Troubleshooting .